# Issue with PDO lastinsertid

Tags: php, mysql, pdo, lastinsertid

I am a beginner programmer and am making a pretty simple insert into database application.

Here is my code:

```
$hostname = 'localhost';
$username = '***********';
$password = '**********';
$conn = new PDO("mysql:host=$hostname;dbname=***********", $username, $password);
$sql = ("INSERT INTO ******** (name, date_entered) VALUES (?, ?)");
$q = $conn->prepare($sql);
$q->execute(array($name, date("Y-m-d")));

var_dump($q); // Trying to figure out what the issue was
echo $sql->lastInsertId();
```

The insert works fine, but I can't get any value of lastInsertId. Why? The results of var_dump($q):

```
object(PDOStatement)#4662 (1) { ["queryString"]=> string(54) "INSERT INTO ******** (name, date_entered) VALUES (?, ?)" }
```

Thanks for any and all help! Its greatly appreciated!

Comment: Turn on error_reporting, because you would be getting something like `Trying to get property on a non-object at line x`  `error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your are trying to execute the lastInsertId-function on a string object; Try this one:

```
echo $conn->lastInsertId();
```